# How can i access laravel session using codeigniter 3?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, laravel-8

I have application built using codeigniter 3, it is a module inside a laravel 8 framework, the laravel framework holds the login and register module, then when a user logged in, it will redirect to my module, but when i print native php `$_SESSION` it does not return any session from laravel.

I have changed the session configuration of laravel inside `config/session` then `'domain' => '.mydomain.com'` but still no session is printed.

I tried to print `$_COOKIE` and it display `ci_session` and `laravel_session` ID.

PS: server Centos 7

Comment: Laravel has not used native php sessions since laravel 5, thats why you cant access it with `$_SESSION` You could try importing it into your own project and getting it set up.

Comment: Thanks, will find another way, maybe thru database.